# How to handle set-cookie headers with fetch() and React Native

Tags: react-native, cookies, fetch, expo

I have spring boot app with cookie-based authentication and session management. 
For the first request I receive cookie names and session hashes as values.

On the other side, I have React Native app wrapped with Expo. 
For the first request ever made I can get this 'set-cookie' header from fetch() request. Then, even after restarting the app, I can't get this header.

I debugged it with React Native Debugger and with this line of code:

```
GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest || GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest;
```

I can see my XHR requests on network tab in debugger. After cleaning all the cookies, every time I'm receiving properly set-cookie header in request's preview. But I can't see it with fetch(...).then(response => response.headers).

Why? It's something persisting my cookie? How to handle cookie data and save it to AsyncStorage without plugins/libraries?

Answer (score 6):

### **Solution:**

If you have **Network Inspect** enabled in React Native Debugger, turn it off. Right click anywhere on the Redux area and press `Disable Network Inspect`.

[image]

#### Notes:

I know this is many years later, but I've found the culprit is React Native Debugger. If you have Network Inspect enabled, it strips the `set-cookie` header away, leaving you with an undefined.

Note that I am using Axios version 0.20.0 and have set `withCredentials` to true in my POST config, on React Native 0.63.3 with React Native Debugger 0.11.5. I know this is not fetch, but it's likely what's ailed you all those years ago. Your `set-cookie` disappeared the moment you started inspecting with RND.

The solution now is to disable Network Inspect, and you'll get your `set-cookie` again.

There is a bug opened in React Native Debugger in 2019, and the author has mentioned this is a limitation that is not easily overcome.

Read more here if you're interested:

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/issues/340#issuecomment-514395195

Comment: This saved me after I thought I hit a wall. So obvious but not....

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch)

> Sending Credentials with a Fetch Request
>
> Should you want to make a fetch request with credentials such as
>   cookies, you should set the credentials of the request to "include".

```
fetch(url, {
  credentials: 'include'
})
```

Comment: It doesn't help :( I have still no cookies in my response's header. I have it only for the first call.

Comment: same issue, did you ever get any resolution on this?